# Obtener valores que tengan dos tipos de X columnas con pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo este enunciado:

**Cuál o cuáles marcas ofrecen dos tipos distintos de combustible?**

He conseguido mostrar la siguiente lista:

```
    make    fuel-type   size
0   alfa-romero gas 3
1   audi    gas 7
2   bmw gas 8
3   chevrolet   gas 3
4   dodge   gas 9
5   honda   gas 13
6   isuzu   gas 4
7   jaguar  gas 3
8   mazda   diesel  2
9   mazda   gas 15
```

En principio, me muestra bien los resultados: mazda tiene dos tipos de combustibles y los demás no. ¿Pero como puedo obtener únicamente la marca mazda, que es la que cumple el enunciado?

Muestro la tabla con este codigo;

```
data.groupby(['make','fuel-type'], as_index=False).size()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Estimado Albarracín, un gusto en saludar

podría ser con el método `nunique()`, de la manera como están organizado tus datos hará un conteo de los datos no únicos en la columna "fuel-type"

```
df = data.groupby(['make']).nunique()
```

me arroja este resultado

```
fuel-type   size
make        
alfa-romero 1   1
audi        1   1
bmw         1   1
chevrolet   1   1
dodge       1   1
honda       1   1
isuzu       1   1
jaguar      1   1
mazda       2   2
```

Verás que la ocurrencia es "mazda" es de 2. luego es filtrar por el contenido mayores o iguales que 2.

```
df[df['fuel-type'] >= 2]
```

si quisieras solo ver los de mayor ocurrencia,este sería el resultado.

```
         fuel-type  size
make        
mazda    2          2
```

Espero haber contribuido a la solución del problema,

saludos